# Question about how to get coordinate point intersect of 2 line in draw i.o

Tags: javascript, html, css, draw

My question is how do get a coordinate point intersect of 2 line in draw i.o

I need a function to resolve this problem in javascript (get coordinate of point only)

Example:

[image: This image for i mean]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the start and end points of both of those lines, you can calculate their slopes. Since you have at least one point you can then compute the slope-intercept form of the lines and set the y's equal to each other to calculate the intersection points' Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Good, this in maths 
in javascript how i cant make this ? @shadkhan

Comment: @MhdJawad You can follow the implementation from this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937782/calculating-the-point-of-intersection-of-two-lines

and adjust your logic as necessary

Comment: @MhdJawad Please close your question by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer that helped you most :)