# Is it possible to determine if a GeoJSON point is inside a GeoJSON polygon using JavasScript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson, point-in-polygon

Is it possible to determine whether a GeoJSON point at a given lat,lon lies within a given GeoJSON polygon using only JavaScript (either through d3, topojson, or any other way)?

For example, I can draw a map showing countries in the UK based on the tutorial [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/).

I then have a some points which have coordinates but no indication as to which country they lie within.

I would like to display a total point count for each country.

Can I work out which country contains each point in the browser, or do I need to preprocess my point data on the server using PostGIS or similar?

Comment: See [*"Node.js/Javascript library to test if point is in geojson multipolygon"*](/q/20379194).

Comment: @altocumulus - Your comment led me to [JavaScript Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) - looks interesting. Also, it would never have occurred to me that 'point-in-polygon' would be a tag.

Comment: Agreed, that [tag:point-in-polygon] tag took me completely by suprise ;-) And there are almost 120 questions associated with it. If you come up with a solution to your problem by yourself, please post an answer to this question.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521982/js-check-if-point-inside-a-polygon

Comment: You can also take a look at https://github.com/turfjs/turf, perhaps too big for this simple task.

Comment: @jonatas_walker Turfjs has a modular ecosystem so you could just use @turfjs/inside via https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-inside or if you don't use npm then find it on github

Comment: @Andi-lo yes, turf did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seems like `d3` has you covered: https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoContains

> d3.geoContains(object, point)
>
> Returns true if and only if the specified GeoJSON object contains the specified point, or false if the object does not contain the point. The point must be specified as a two-element array [longitude, latitude] in degrees. For Point and MultiPoint geometries, an exact test is used; for a Sphere, true is always returned; for other geometries, an epsilon threshold is applied.

Comment: This is correct. It would be fair to note, though, that this is a new method of D3 **v4** and was not available at the time the question was posted. However, as the question is not targeting any specific version, this answer totally legit.

Comment: I can't get this work. `geoContains` returns `false` for point which is actually a center of area. I validated geoJson of this area (it's valid) and checked on google maps if given point belongs to this area (it belongs).

Comment: So it seems to my polygon be counterclockwise, but `d3` expects clockwise.   I tested `turf` library (thx to Jonatas Walker comment for aiming to) and it 'eats' counterclockwise polygon.

Comment: If you are using typescript, make sure you npm i @types/d3 instead of npm i d3. I spend like a day trying to find a library for my angular project.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding the **@thedude** answer's you can also use [geojson-lookup](https://github.com/simonepri/geojson-geometries-lookup) if you need to do this check more than once on a given GeoJSON.

Comment: It is better to use the link as a reference and put the key points in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

[Turf.js](https://turfjs.org) provides a function called [boolean-point-in-polygon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon)

For example:

```
var pt = turf.point([-77, 44]);

var poly = turf.polygon([[
  [-81, 41],
  [-81, 47],
  [-72, 47],
  [-72, 41],
  [-81, 41]
]]);

turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, poly);
//= true
```

Comment: that's a great library. Can you fix the link? it's pointing to https://tufjs.org (missing r)

Comment: Good catch, fixed. Thanks!