# Keep getting TypeError when using collision function

Tags: javascript, function, collision

[image]

I keep getting this error when using `points[i+2]`, it doesn't return an error, but doesn't work as supposed to either when using `points[i+1]` (line 60). I can't seem to figure out why this error is happening. I looked in the console and don't know what `undefined` *should* be.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var GLOBAL = {};

var point1 = [300, 300];
var point2 = [245, 55];
var point3 = [23, 143];
var point4 = [40, 200];

/*
 * y = mx + b
 * b = y - mx
 * m = y - b/x
 * x = y - b/m
 */
function lineSide(a, b, c) {
  var m = (b[1] - a[1]) / (b[0] - a[0]);
  var b = a[1] - (m * a[0]);

  var result = function(x, y) {
    if (y < m * x + b) return 0;
    else if (y > m * x + b) return 1;
    else if (y == m * x + b) return 2;
    //TODO implement error handling
  }(c[0], c[1]);

  switch (result) {
    case 0:
      return 'lt';
      break;
    case 1:
      return 'gt';
      break;
    case 2:
      return 'eq';
      break;
    default:
      return 'asdf';
      break;
  }
}

function inBounds(p, points) {
  var bcheck = [],
    pcheck = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var pointa, pointb;
    if (i + 1 >= points.length) {
      pointa = points[i];
      pointb = points[0];
      bcheck.push(lineSide(pointa, pointb, points[1]));
    } else {
      pointa = points[i];
      pointb = points[i + 1];
      console.log(i + 2);
      console.log(points[i + 2]);
      bcheck.push(lineSide(pointa, pointb, points[i + 2])); // <-- THE PROBLEM AREA.
    }
  }
  // console.log(bcheck);

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var pointa, pointb;
    if (i + 1 >= points.length) {
      pointa = points[i];
      pointb = points[0];
      pcheck.push(lineSide(pointa, pointb, p));
    } else {
      pointa = points[i];
      pointb = points[i + 1];
      pcheck.push(lineSide(pointa, pointb, p));
    }
  }

  console.log(pcheck)
  for (var i in bcheck) {
    if (bcheck[i] != pcheck[i]) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  GLOBAL.mouseX = e.clientX;
  GLOBAL.mouseY = e.clientY;
}

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  if (inBounds([GLOBAL.mouseX, GLOBAL.mouseY], [point1, point2, point3, point4])) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  } else {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(point1[0], point1[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(point2[0], point2[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(point3[0], point3[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(point4[0], point4[1]);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop inside `inBounds()` needs to be adjusted.

Either line 60 needs to only add by one:

```
bcheck.push(lineSide(pointa, pointb, points[i + 1])); // <-- THE PROBLEM AREA.
```

Or the if block on line 51 needs to add by two:

```
if (i + 2 >= points.length) {
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with the loop, so adjust as necessary.

[jsFiddle of option #2.](https://jsfiddle.net/mLt6wktk/)

The shape highlighting seems to break when the cursor exits through the bottom border. That's because the `onmousemove` event is only on the canvas element. You can change that event to be on the entire document, or add an `onmouseleave` event to the canvas element.

```
canvas.onmouseleave = function(e) {
    GLOBAL.mouseX = undefined;
    GLOBAL.mouseY = undefined;
};
```

Comment: `c` is defined by `points[i]` in the function `inBounds`, but on the last iteriation of the array `points`, `c` becomes undefined, i can't figure out why

Comment: Sorry, I missed where you were defining `points`. It's an array of arrays, the issues was with your loop.

Comment: I'm trying to detect collision between the mouse and the shape defined by `points[]`

Comment: The jsFiddle does that except for when the mouse leaves the shape through the bottom border.

Comment: That's the problem

Comment: @spacegeek224 you asked why you were getting the exception. I'll update to include info on why the shape isn't turning black.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115987/discussion-between-fotijr-and-spacegeek224).

Comment: I answered the original question, please consider marking the answer as accepted or updating your question. I also refactored you logic in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xhsz1zL/) by applying [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521982/js-check-if-point-inside-a-polygon).