# Find Markers IDs Inside Drawn Polygon in Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there a way to do that on google map which I have markers in that map and when I draw a polygon I want to get all markers ids only inside polygon?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can iterate through your markers and check which are [inside the polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521982/js-check-if-point-inside-a-polygon) then store them in an array.