# Is it possible to use HTML image maps within an A-Frame scene?

Tags: hyperlink, aframe, imagemap

**Here's the scenario:**

I have a 360º panorama image of the world map, running on A-Frame

I would like each continent to be clickable, redirecting to a related Wikipedia page.

**What I tried:**

- I tried using the `<map>` tag as I would in a normal project, but
  with no results.
- I also read the documentation, and found nothing
  relevant about this.

**My question:**

Is my goal even possible? If so, how?

**My code:**

Note: So far, only the African continent has coordinates.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmg0yL7u/)

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>

<a-scene>
  <a-entity camera look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true"></a-entity>
  <a-sky id="image-360" radius="10" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg/1920px-Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg" usemap="#image_map"></a-sky>
  
  <map name="image_map">
    <area alt="Africa" title="Africa" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa" coords="920,296 871,351 873,424 916,461 979,449 1014,463 1005,490 1032,540 1020,579 1056,663 1081,667 1114,655 1146,600 1175,561 1165,504 1220,451 1228,422 1191,426 1124,314 1063,308 1054,324 1014,302 1016,284 963,290" shape="polygon">
  </map>
  
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<map>` tag places the areas above an image. It won't project the areas onto a three dimentional object just like that.

I'd recommend an approach where you re-use the areas defined in the `<map>` tag within an a-frame custom component.

**tldr:**

I've made [a component](https://github.com/gftruj/unnecessary-components/tree/main/src/asourcemap) that seems to do the job, and is fairly simple in use:

```
<a-image material="src: #texture" asourcemap="#some-map"></a-image>
<!-- somewhere else -->
<map id="some-map">
   <area shape="rect" alt="rectangle" coords="0,0, 50,50" href="rect.html">
   <area shape="polygon" alt="poly" coords="0,0, 40,50, 25,0">
</map>
```

It should work well with the `href` attribute, but also the `<a-image>` will emit a signal with the clicked area name.

You can see it working with 3D planes and cylinders [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/map_tag.html).

**end of tldr**

**0. Gathering `<map>` data**

Simple parsing. Grab the `<map>` element, iterate through all children, and collect their data with `getAttribute()`:

```
var map = document.querySelector(selector);
for (let area of map.children) {
   // area.getAttribute("href") - href attribute
   // area.getAttribute("alt") - alt name
   // area.getAttribute("coords") - coordinates array. 
}
```

Store them for later use. The coordinates are comma separated strings, so you may need to `parseInt()` them, manage the order (i.e. `[[x1,x1], [x2,y2], [x3, y3]]`)

**1. Make the a-frame entity interactable**

React on clicks, and what's more important - check where the click occurred:

```
this.el.addEventListener("click", evt => {
   var UVPoint = evt.detail.intersection.uv
})
```

[UV mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping) will help us determine which point on the texture was clicked. The UV ranges from <0, 1>, so we will need to re-scale the UVPoint:

```
// may need waiting for "model-loaded"
let mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh")
// this may not be available immidiately
let image = mesh.material.map.image
let x_on_image = UVPoint * image.width
// the y axis goes from <1, 0>
let y_on_image = image.height - UVPoint * image.heigth
```

So hey, we got the area coordinates and the point coordinates!
There is only one thing left:

**2. Determining if an area was clicked**

No need to re-invent the wheel here. [This SO question on checking if a point is inside a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521982/check-if-point-is-inside-a-polygon) has a simple `inside(point, polygon)` function. Actually we have everything we need, so the last thing we do is:

- iterate through the polygons
- check if the clicked point is inside any of the polygons
- if positive - do your thing

like this:

```
var point = [x_on_texture, y_on_texture]
for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
   // polygons need to be [[x1, y1], [x2, y2],...[xn, yn]] here
   if (inside(point, polygons[i]) {
      console.log("polygon", i, "clicked!")
   }
}
```

If you skipped the **tldr** section - the above steps are combined in [this component](https://github.com/gftruj/unnecessary-components/blob/main/src/asourcemap/asourcemap.js) and used in [this example](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/map_tag.html)

**3. Old, hacky try**

Another way of doing this could be:

- receive a click on the a-frame entity
- grab the clicked coordinates like in *1*
- hide the scene
- check out which `<area>` is at the coordinates with `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);`.
- show the scene
- create a mouse event with `document.createEvent("MouseEvent");`
- dispatch it on the `<area>` element.

The hide / show trick works really good even on my mobile phone. I was really surprised that the scene wasn't flickering, freezing, even slowing down.

But `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);` didn't work with firefox, and probably any attempt to make it work would be way more time consuming than the **0**-**2** steps. Also I believe the trappings would become bigger and case-dependant.

Anyway, here's the *old-answer* component:

```
/* SETUP
<a-scene>
 <a-image press-map>
</a-scene>

<image id="image" sourcemap="map">
<map name="map">
  <area ...>
</map>
*/

AFRAME.registerComponent("press-map", {
  init: function() {
    // the underlying image
    this.img = document.querySelector("#image")
    // react on clicks
    this.el.addEventListener("click", evt => {
      // get the point on the UV
      let uvPoint = evt.detail.intersection.uv 
      // the y is inverted
      let pointOnImage = {
        x: uvPoint.x * this.img.width,
        y: this.img.height - uvPoint.y * this.img.height
      }
      
      // the ugly show-hide bits
      this.el.sceneEl.style.display = "none";
      this.img.style.display = "block";
      // !! grab the <area> at the (x,y) position
      var el = document.elementFromPoint(pointOnImage.x, pointOnImage.y);
      this.el.sceneEl.style.display="block"
      this.img.style.display="none"

      // create and dispatch the event
      var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
      ev.initMouseEvent(
            "click",
            true /* bubble */, false /* cancelable */,
            window, null,
            x, y, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
            false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
            0 /*left*/, null
      );
      el.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This is hacky indeed. But it does the job! It doesn't work in Firefox though. Any idea why?

Comment: @MikeMichaels didn't notice, it seems that `elementFromPoint` are not grabbing areas on firefox. Not sure why, nonetheless it seems it would be better to find a non hacky solution, because it gets way too convoluded :)

Comment: @MikeMichaels Since the solution was not only hacky, but as you noticed completely unreliable - I've edited my answer and based it on a solution that should be working on any browser / platform. Let me know if you like it. Also it's pretty late here, so if something is unclear, or badly edited feel free to point it out.