# MySQL ST_CONTAINS returns false for MULTIPOLYGON with more than 1 polygon

Tags: mysql, geospatial, spatial, point-in-polygon

I have a bunch of locations (points) with coordinates stored as geometry points. I've imported spatial data of provinces in my country and I'm trying to determine the province in which each location lays, which worked for 26 of 28 provinces in total.

Before importing the data I noticed that all provinces had their geometries defined as `POLYGON` except the two in question that were defined as `MULTIPOLYGON`, so for consistency's sake I converted all to `MULTIPOLYGON` where the majority contain data for just 1 polygon.

I am testing now with one province which contains 3 polygon geometries in its `MULTIPOLYGON` definition. The point I'm testing with is contained within the third polygon, I have confirmed this by testing all 3 manually using the function found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521982/check-if-point-is-inside-a-polygon):

[image: code]

Here's my SQL which returns 0 (on pastebin because SO won't let me post it here)

https://pastebin.com/raw/bkNeBgcL

If I remove the first two polygons, then it returns 1

https://pastebin.com/raw/UfTax1K5

If I'd had to guess what's going wrong is that mysql is expecting the point to be in all 3 polygons at the same time? And I need to tell it to return true if it is in any of the polygons inside the multi-polygon, but how?

Comment: please add your queries as text not images

Comment: @IanTurton my queries are text, but stackoverflow has 30k char limit so I can't post them here..