# Check if (pos/neg) polygon is inside another (pos/neg) polygon

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, polygon, point-in-polygon

### Description

I have the problem to decide if a region `A` is inside a region `B`. These regions are defined by a list of vertices `polyA` and `polyB`:

- If the vertices `polyA` are counter-clockwise,

  - then `A` is the interior region (purple) and `areaA > 0`
    (positive polygon)
- Else,

  - `A` is the exterior region (pink) and `areaA < 0`  (negative polygon)

[image: Example of internal and external regions]

I got in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833802/check-if-polygon-is-inside-a-polygon) which is a sub-problem of mine: It solves when `areaA > 0` and `areaB > 0`. Since my problem is more general, the given solution is not enough.

### Problem

So far, I verify if all the vertices `polyA` are inside `polyB` and if there are intersections, but it gives wrong results when

1. The 'minor' polygon is negative and 'major' polygon is positive, with same center

```py
polyA = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1)]  # Clockwise square of side 1
polyB = [(0, 0), (3, 0), (3, 3), (0, 3)]  # Counter-clockwise square of side 3
polygon_in_polygon(polyA, polyB)  # Expect False
# Gives True since all vertices polyA are inside B
```

2. `polyA` is the inverse of `polyB`

```py
polyA = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]  # Counter-clockwise square of side 1
polyB = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]  # Clockwise square of side 1
polygon_in_polygon(polyA, polyB)  # Expect False
# Gives True, cause all the vertices polyA are in the boundary of B
```

Can anyone help me finding an algorithm for it?

### Current algorithm

So far my algorithm (in python) is

```py
def polygon_and_polygon(polyA: tuple[Point], polyB: tuple[Point]) -> bool:
    """Checks the intersections of polyA and polyB
    
    Returns False if there are any point in each segment of A which is outside B
    """
    ...

def point_in_polygon(point: Point, polygon: tuple[Point]) -> bool:
    """Checks if given point is inside the region made by polygon"""
    area = compute_area(polygon)  # area > 0 if polygon is counter-clockwise
                                  # area < 0 else
    wind = winding_number(point, polygon)
    return wind == 1 if area > 0 else wind == 0

def polygon_in_polygon(polyA: tuple[Point], polyB: tuple[Point]) -> bool:
    """Checks if polyA is completely inside polyB"""
    for point in polyA:
        if not point_in_polygon(point, polyB):
            return False
    if polygon_and_polygon(polyA, polyB):
        return False
    # Insert code here
    return True
```

I expect hints or an algorithm so the function `polygon_in_polygon` is able to treat the 2 presented cases, or also some problems which may arrive and I don't see them yet.

I thought about creating some random points `rand_point` which are inside `A`, and verify if they are inside `B`. But it's possible to have a bad luck and get `(0, 1)` in the first example which is indeed inside `B`, but `A` is not inside `B`.

### Additional info

**Note 1:** Consider the coordinates of each point are integers: disregard `float` precision problem

**Note 2:** The regions `A` and `B` are closed sets. That means, if an edge `edgeA` touches an edge `edgeB`, but doesn't cross `edgeB`, we consider `edgeA` is inside `B`. Therefore

```py
polyA = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)]  # Positive triangle of side 1
polyB = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)]  # Positive square of side 1
polygon_in_polygon(polyA, polyB)  # Expect True

polyA = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]  # Negative square of side 1
polyB = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)]  # Negative triangle of side 1
polygon_in_polygon(polyA, polyB)  # Expect True
```

Comment: Furthermore, only checking points is not sufficient, because even if all points of B are inside A, edges of B can intersect edges of A. You could take a look at the `shapely` library to solve at least part of your problem.

Comment: Check no edge in A intersects any edge of B. (Could be a tad expensive.) If there are no edge intersections then A either lies wholly inside B or wholly outside it - which can be checked with a single point.