# Google map draw polygons and alert on overlapping

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am  drawing different polygons on google map. I need when user draws polygon, if polygon overlap with any other polygon then user get warning alert, ( You can't draw overlapped polygon).

Please check Example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

I have done drawing different polygons. but I could not find prevent overlapping. 
Please help me, how I show alert when polygon is overlapped with other polygon

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to keep track of all existing polygon coordinates.

2) You will need a polygon overlapping algorithm, [example for convex polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753140/how-do-i-determine-if-two-convex-polygons-intersect).

2b) If your polygons are non-convex, you either need to find appropriate algorithm or split them into convex elements (triangles?) to be able to use 2).

3) [Javascript alerts](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)